Prestashop Module Development 1.6.1.24
When I connect my custom module controller to my main module file and configure the module with a form, it redirects me to the home of the admin dashboard. However, I want to execute my controller.
I need to use
$this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminMatriculeCheckerController.php') 

with Controller.php appended at the end to make it work (it redirects only to the homepage without an error of controller not found).
I want to parse my .xlsx file and compare it to my customers to show a color for matricule (unique identifier) in the customer grid.
Here is my structure:
matriculechecker/
├── MatriculeChecker.php
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── config_fr.xml
├── controllers
│   └── admin
│       └── AdminMatriculeCheckerController.php
├── matricule_checker.tpl
└── views
    ├── css
    │   └── matricule_checker.css
    └── js
        └── matricule_checker.js

6 directories, 8 files
Here is my code:
MatriculeChecker.php:
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class MatriculeChecker extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'matriculechecker';
        $this->tab = 'administration';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Judikaël Bellance';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        parent::__construct();
        $this->displayName = $this->l('MatriculeChecker');
        $this->description = $this->l('A module to check matricules.');
        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
        $this->context = ContextCore::getContext();
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        $output = null;

        if (Tools::isSubmit('submit' . $this->name)) {
            $this->processUpload();
        }

        $this->context->smarty->assign([
            'upload_action' => $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminMatriculeChecker'),
            'advice' => $this->l('Please upload a file containing matricules to check.'),
            'submit' => $this->l('Envoyer'),
            'link_advice' => $this->l('Need help?'),
        ]);

        return $output . $this->displayForm();
    }

    public function displayForm()
    {
        return $this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'matriculechecker/matricule_checker.tpl');
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader') &&
            $this->registerHook('actionCustomerGridQueryBuilderModifier');
    }

    public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path . 'views/js/matricule_checker.js');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path . 'views/css/matricule_checker.css');
    }

    public function hookActionCustomerGridQueryBuilderModifier($params)
    {
        // Update the matricule style in the customer grid
    }

    protected function processUpload()
    {
        if (isset($_FILES['matricule_file']) && $_FILES['matricule_file']['error'] == 0) {
            $filePath = $_FILES['matricule_file']['tmp_name'];
            $fileType = IOFactory::identify($filePath);
            $reader = IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
            $spreadsheet = $reader->load($filePath);

            $matricules = [];
            foreach ($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

                foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                    $matricules[] = $cell->getValue();
                }
            }

            $this->compareMatricules($matricules);
        }
    }

    protected function compareMatricules($matricules)
    {
        var_dump($matricules);
    }
}

AdminMatriculeCheckerController.php:
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'matriculechecker/vendor/autoload.php';

class AdminMatriculeCheckerController extends ModuleAdminControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();
        $this->context = ContextCore::getContext();
    }

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitUpload')) {
            $this->processUpload();
        }

        $this->context->smarty->assign([
            'upload_action' => $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminMatriculeChecker'),
            'submit' => $this->l('Envoyer')
        ]);

        $this->setTemplate('authentication.tpl');
    }

    /**
     * @throws \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception
     */
    protected function processUpload(): bool
    {
        if (isset($_FILES['matricule_file']) && $_FILES['matricule_file']['error'] == 0) {
            $filePath = $_FILES['matricule_file']['tmp_name'];
            $fileType = IOFactory::identify($filePath);
            $reader = IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
            $spreadsheet = $reader->load($filePath);

            $matricules = [];
            foreach ($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

                foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                    $matricules[] = $cell->getValue();
                }
            }

            return $this->compareMatricules($matricules);
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = $this->l('An error occurred while uploading the file.');
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected function compareMatricules($matricules): bool
    {
        var_dump($matricules);

        $customers = Customer::getCustomers();
        foreach ($customers as $customer) {
            if (in_array($customer['matricule'], $matricules)) {
                $customer = new Customer($customer['id_customer']);
                $customer->active = 0;
                $customer->update();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}


Do not employ the use keyword for your main module class or it will cause problems with this old PrestaShop version.
